# When does a trigonometric equation have a unique solution?

Tags: trigonometry

When do a trigonometric equation have a unique solution? Or what is the condition for a trigonometric equation to have a unique solution?

I found the need of that condition in question below

> The value of $k$ if the equation $2\cos x + \cos 2kx = 3$
>   has only one solution is
>   \begin{align}
> \text{a. }&  0 & \text{b. } & 2 \\
> \text{c. }&  \sqrt2 & \text{d. } & 1/2 \\
> \end{align}

And the answer is (C)

(Image of original problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hi57.jpg)

Comment: Hint : Both $\cos(x)$ and $\cos(2kx)$ must be equal to $1$. $\cos(x)=1$ is true if and only if $x$ is an integer mutliple of $2\pi$

Comment: That will imply x=2nπ then?

Comment: Yes, exactly that.

Comment: Try $k=\sqrt{2}$. You will see that only $x=0$ is possible.

Comment: Ok I got it ,but what if it was subjective question?

Comment: What will be the subjective approach?

Comment: What is a "subjective" question?

Comment: A question in which there are no options and one is supposed to right a full solution

Comment: It can be very hard to find the number of real solutions for a trigonometric equation , in particular if we allow $x$ to occur as well, for example $2\sin(x)=x$.

Answer (score 1):

As already said we need $\cos(x)=1$ and $\cos(2kx)=1$ , hence $x=2n\pi$ , $n\in\mathbb Z$

This implies $2kx=4kn\pi$. In the cases $k=0,k=2$ and $k=1/2$, every integer $n$ gives a solution. If $k=\sqrt{2}$, $4kn\pi$ cannot be an integer multiple of $2\pi$ , unless $k=0$ because $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational.

So, $c)$ is the only correct answer based on the fact that $k$ is irrational.

Comment: I wanted to classify the real pairs $(a/b)$, such that the equation $a\cdot \sin(x)+b\cdot\cos(x)=x$ has exactly one real solution. It turned out to be difficult and I do not have a complete solution yet.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the problem that you received is poorly worded
(and that is putting it kindly).

As we have seen, $2\cos x + \cos (2kx) = 3$
if and only if $\cos x = 1$ and $\cos (2kx) = 1$.
That in turn will occur if and only if both $x$ and $2kx$ are
integer multiples of $2\pi$,
or in other words, 
setting $n = \frac{x}{2\pi}$,
if $n$ is an integer and $2kn$ also is an integer.

Clearly this is true for $n = 0$, so there is always at least one solution of
$2\cos x + \cos (2kx) = 3$.
If $k$ is rational, then we can always find a positive integer $n$
such that $2kn$ is an integer, so there is a second solution.
But if $k$ is irrational then there is no integer $n$ (other than $n=0$)
such that $2kn$ is an integer.

We can conclude this: if all we know is that
$2\cos x + \cos (2kx) = 3$ has only one solution,
it is nonsense to say that "the" value of $k$ "is" $\sqrt2$.
Any irrational number could be the value of $k$.
If I needed to answer this question for an exam, I would assume that
the intention of the writer of the exam was for me to identify a
number that *could* be the value of $k$, and in the multiple-choice format
as written there is only one correct choice, $\sqrt2$.
All the other choices are rational numbers.

If the question did not limit the answer to that particular
restricted list of four choices of values of $k$,
but let you write the response freely,
the correct answer would be that $k$ "is" an irrational number.